# Showing a progress wheel in a widget

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, progress, android-wheel

I have a widget that gets updated when I press it, but I would like to show a progress wheel while the widget gets updated.

```
//remove text      
        updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_textview, View.GONE);
        updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_dkk, View.GONE);

// show progress wheel

updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_Pross, View.VISIBLE);



// task that take time are locatet here a GetHTTP function



//Show text again       
        updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_textview, View.VISIBLE);
        updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_dkk, View.VISIBLE);

// Remove progress wheel

   updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_Pross, View.GONE);
```

ALL this are locatet this in my widget update class:

```
public static RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context context) {
```

But the progress wheel does not show. It's like the widget only get updated one time, and thereby not showing the progress wheel while computing in the GetHttp.

EDIT:

```
// Remove rext and show progress wheel
    updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_textview, View.GONE);
        updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_dkk, View.GONE);
        updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_Pross, View.VISIBLE);

    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, SaldoWidget.class);
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);


//    GetHttp code here / long computing task her

 //Show text and remove progress wheel 
 updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_textview, View.VISIBLE);
            updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_dkk, View.VISIBLE);
            updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_Pross, View.GONE);
            manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget()` every time you want to change the layout.

That means you have to hide the original widget views and show the progressbar in your `RemoteViews`. After that, call `updateAppWidget()` to change the layout and display the progressbar. Then execute your downloadtask. After that, populate the views with the fetched data, hide the progress indicator and call `updateAppWidget()` again to change it back to the normal layout.

The name `RemoteViews` may make this a bit confusing at the start. It's actually not a bunch of `Views` that you can control remotely from your app. It's a group of views that you build up to your needs and then you give it to the AppWidgetManager to publish it.